# Find $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{1!+3!+\ldots+(2n-1)!}{2!+4!+\ldots+(2n)!}$

Tags: limits, factorial

> $$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{1!+3!+\ldots+(2n-1)!}{2!+4!+\ldots+(2n)!}$$

I have tried some standard approaches like dividing by $(2n)!$ and comparing consecutive terms. Hint, please :) Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Morally: The last term in the denominator is $n$ times larger than the last term in the numerator, and all lower terms are negligible since they're smaller by a factor on the order $n^2$. This kills the limit. There is a minor technicality to be overcome, since there are still $n$ terms in the numerator.

---

This can be estimated very brutally. The bottom is at least $(2n)!$, while the numerator is at most $(2n - 1)! + n \cdot (2n - 3)!$. This leads to

\begin{align*}
\frac{(2n - 1)! + n (2n - 3)!}{(2n)!} &= \frac{\big((2n - 1)(2n - 2) + n\big)(2n - 3)!}{(2n)(2n - 1)(2n - 2)(2n - 3)!}  \\
&= \frac{4n^2 + O(n)}{8n^3 + O(n^2)} \to 0
\end{align*}

Comment: The $O(\cdot)$ in the denominator should be $O(n^2)$, shouldn't it?

Comment: @ClementC. Quite right, thanks.

Comment: @user, maybe in the first fraction only $(2n)!$ should be in the denominator?

Comment: Sorry, I do not get the factorization in the denominator. Am I missing something or do I need another coffee?

Comment: @user35603 Yes, my apologies - that was left from a first draft.

Comment: @MiguelAtencia Sorry, that was left from a first draft. Should be fixed now.